# Where I can get EOS tokens number precision information

Tags: eosio.token

Where can I check EOS tokens(EOSDT, Everipedia, Newdex, etc) precision points?

Answer (score 1):

If the token is based off the eosio.token contract, you could get the stat table and see what the precision is there. For example, for EOS

```
$ cleos get table eosio.token EOS stat
{
  "rows": [{
      "supply": "1024177197.2358 EOS",
      "max_supply": "10000000000.0000 EOS",
      "issuer": "eosio"
    }
  ],
  "more": false
}
```

For EOSDT

```
$ cleos get table eosdtsttoken EOSDT stat
{
  "rows": [{
      "supply": "5562623.798696016 EOSDT",
      "max_supply": "70000000.000000000 EOSDT",
      "issuer": "eosdtcntract"
    }
  ],
  "more": false
}
```

Source: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/7740#issuecomment-521633972